# Knowledge Sites page not displaying

Tags: force.com-sites, knowledge

I have installed the Knowledge application from the appexchange:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU

I have followed all the steps in the installation guide but when I click on my sites link it shows the under constructions page.

Here is images of my config.

[image: PKB settings]

[image: Knowledge config]

[image: Sites config]

[image: This is what it is showing]

Comment: Have you checked that the profile you are using has security permissions to the VF page being displayed?

Comment: Yes look at the LCKnowledge Sites image you will see under Visualforce pages pkb_Home and pkb_Home is my Active Site Home Page.

Comment: Debug as an admin and see if any errors .Preview as an admin should help you to debug issues .

Comment: Previewed as admin still gives me the same page. I have a custom domain may that be the problem?

Comment: No never .Whats your first page on site and whats the error page you have set for sites in sfdc?

Comment: My first Page is pkb_Home and my error page is Maintenance Page(500/503)

Comment: I removed the error page and now I get: Authorization Required. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why my page did not display is the following. In the Public Access Profile you need to go to Object Settings. There each of your article categories will be an object and you need to specify the access there. In the image below my article category was Borrower. I gave read access and also read access to the solution.

[image]

Do this for all your article categories and you will be fine.